# What is the fastest pseudo index in Redis?

Tags: database-design, indexing, redis

The Little Book of Redis explains how to lookup a user id by email address so you can then lookup the user hash by user id and get the full user object. It's effectively an index on the users by email address. You just need to add to the lookup hash every time you insert a new user like this:

```
set users:9001 "{id: 9001, email: leto@dune.gov, ...}"
hset users:lookup:email leto@dune.gov 9001
```

This operation seems to me involve a hidden lookup inside the hash that Redis must perform to pull out the value for the required email field. There could be thousands of email fields and we're asking for just one of them.

How about using the email in the index key like this :

```
set users:9001 "{id: 9001, email: leto@dune.gov, ...}"
set users:lookup:email:leto@dune.gov 9001
```

Because this wasn't suggested in the Little Book of Redis I presume it's not best practice.

Can anyone explain why the first method is better? Are they effectively the same?

Thanks, I'm learning Redis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I see it, each method has its own benefits and drawbacks:

The hash method:

- You can get a list of all emails (keys) or ID's (values) fairly quickly (O(N), where N is the number of entries in the map)
- For small number of entries, it will be quite memory efficient (pretty small though, probably not applicable for any real use-cases)
- You are limited to 2^32-1 entries (again, might not be an issue, unless you plan on a majority of the people on earth to use your application)
- *slightly* slower, since redis needs to do two O(1) lookups instead of just one... Marginal difference, if at all noticeable.
- Not shard friendly, since they will all be in the same redis instance.

The key method:

- No limit to number of entries
- As fast as it's going to be
- Only possible to get a list of all users by using `KEY`, which is O(n) (for each entry in the database - a big no-no for live environments)
- Shard friendly

Those are all the differences I can think of. I tend to lean towards the key method unless I need to list all users for some reason, just because it's more straight-forward and scales better with sharding.

As an aside, I would probably not store JSON data as the user data if I can avoid it, because it will likely be more memory-efficient to store the fields in a hash. Also, you can just get and set the fields you really need a certain point, rather than the whole blob. It's also possible to do increments in the hash atomically without transactions, which can be useful. But it all depends on your data... If you have a large nested structure, it might be easiest to just serialize it and throw it in there instead of creating lots of different native structures and link them together.

Comment: This blog post explains that multiple keys cost 3X more ram than hashes, but it might not apply to the limited data scope of my question : http://blog.gomiso.com/2011/05/24/how-redis-can-ruin-your-day-and-what-you-can-do-to-fix-it/